# How to render HTML from a property of items being displayed with v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js

I send an array of objects which each have a `.html` property that has HTML text in it, e.g. `<h1>...</h1>` or `<h2>...</h2>`

I want to have the HTML from each item display one after another in the DOM, like this:

```
<h1>...</h1>
<h2>...</h2>
<h2>...</h2>
<h1>...</h1>
<h2>...</h2>
```

However, all of these attempts do not work:

1. `<div v-for="item in outlineItems" v-html="item.html"></div>`

   - displays HTML wrapped in divs: `<div><h1>...</h1></div>` and `<div><h2>...</h2></div>`
2. `<template v-for="item in outlineItems" v-html="item.html"></template>`

   - displays nothing
3. `<template v-for="item in outlineItems">{{item.html}}</template>`

   - displays the literal HTML instead of rendering it
4. `<template v-for="item in items"><template v-html="item.html"></template></template>`

   - displays nothing

How can I simply display the contents of the `.html` property of each item so that the HTML in it renders, without any wrapping elements on it?

Comment: I think you can creat a custom component which will have a **slot** inside of this slot you should be able to put your raw html without any wraper

Comment: where is the html coming from? is it possible to create seperate component types and then loop through the components (for example `<component v-for="my_component in items" :is="my_component">`)?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it using a single wrapper element for the whole lot by concatenating all the HTML in a computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      outlineItems: [
        { html: '<h1>Heading 1</h1>' },
        { html: '<h2>Heading 2</h2>' },
        { html: '<h3>Heading 3</h3>' }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    outlineHtml () {
      return this.outlineItems.map(item => item.html).join('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-html="outlineHtml"></div>  
</div>
```

Behind the scenes `v-html` sets the `innerHTML` of its corresponding DOM node. A `<template>` tag doesn't create a DOM node so the `innerHTML` can't be set anywhere.

I would add that `v-html` is considered an 'escape hatch'. Where possible you should avoid using it and let Vue create the HTML itself. Generally the approach would be to use a suitable data structure to hold the data (rather than a blob of markup) and then render that data structure within the template.

Comment: To provide explanation why `<template v-html>` does not work, is because `<template>` is simply a placeholder and does not actually render to anything, so it cannot have its innerHTML set because it is not an actual DOM node per se :)

Comment: @Terry Thanks. I've added a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create multiple unique components. You can even pass in props, and there are no wrappers

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<h1>Welcome to coligo!</h1>'
});
Vue.component('titles', {
  template: '<h1>title 1</h1>'
});
Vue.component('title2', {
  template: '<h2>Welcome to coligo!</h2>'
});
Vue.component('title3', {
  template: '<h3>{{text}}</h3>',
  props: ['text']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   items: [
     { type: 'greeting' },
     { type: 'titles' },
     { type: 'title2' },
     { type: 'title3', text: 'test' }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <component v-for="(item,i) in items" :is="item.type" :text="item.text" :key="i"></component>  
</div>
```